# Objective C: Best way to determine if a dictionary key inside an array exists?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, dictionary

In this example, I am trying to grab all the name values in `dictionaries` inside an `Array`. The following code works well.

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"name" : @"joe"},
                   @{@"name" : @"john"},
                   @{@"name" : @"jack"}];

NSArray *nameArray = [array valueForKey:@"name"];                                                   
NSLog(@"name array is %@",nameArray);
```

However, if the array is following

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"foo" : @"joe"},
                       @{@"foo" : @"john"},
                       @{@"foo" : @"jack"}];
```

I will get an array of nulls. Is there a way to check if the `name` key exists first?  The only solution I came up with is to create an `NSMutableArray` and loop through all the keys and make sure the value isn't null and add it to the `NSMutableArray`. The code below shows how I do it.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (id string in nameArray) {
     if ([string isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
          [mutableArray addObject:string];
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `valueForKey:` if the key might not be there and you don't want nulls in your resulting array. Just iterate the array yourself.

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"name" : @"joe"},
                   @{@"name" : @"john"},
                   @{@"name" : @"jack"}];

NSMutableArray *nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    NSString *name = dict[@"name"];
    if (name) {
        [nameArray addObject:name];
    }
}
```